# Creating a table from a variable inside a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am writing a for loop to calculate the value of four different variables. The first variable is M. M increases from 10^2 to 10^5,

```
M = [10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5];
```

The other three variables needed for the table are shown in the code below.

```
confmc
confcv
confmcSize/confcvSize
```

I first create a for loop to iterate through the four different values of M. I then create the table outside of the for loop.

How could I adjust the implementation so that the table displays all four values of M?

```
randn('state',100)

%%%%%% Problem and method parameters %%%%%%%%%
S = 5; E = 6; sigma = 0.3; r = 0.05; T = 1;
Dt = 1e-2; N = T/Dt; M = [10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

for k=1:numel(M)
    %%%%%%%%% Geom Asian exact mean  %%%%%%%%%%%%
    sigsqT= sigma^2*T*(N+1)*(2*N+1)/(6*N*N);
    muT = 0.5*sigsqT + (r - 0.5*sigma^2)*T*(N+1)/(2*N);

    d1 = (log(S/E) + (muT + 0.5*sigsqT))/(sqrt(sigsqT));
    d2 = d1 - sqrt(sigsqT);

    N1 = 0.5*(1+erf(d1/sqrt(2)));
    N2 = 0.5*(1+erf(d2/sqrt(2)));

    geo =  exp(-r*T)*( S*exp(muT)*N1 - E*N2 );
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    Spath = S*cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt+sigma*sqrt(Dt)*randn(M(k),N)),2);

    % Standard Monte Carlo
    arithave = mean(Spath,2);
    Parith = exp(-r*T)*max(arithave-E,0);  % payoffs 
    Pmean = mean(Parith);
    Pstd = std(Parith);
    confmc = [Pmean-1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k)), Pmean+1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k))];
    confmcSize = [(Pmean+1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k)))-(Pmean-1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k)))];

    % Control Variate
    geoave = exp((1/N)*sum(log(Spath),2));
    Pgeo = exp(-r*T)*max(geoave-E,0);      % geo payoffs 
    Z = Parith + geo - Pgeo;               % control variate version
    Zmean = mean(Z);
    Zstd = std(Z);
    confcv = [Zmean-1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k)), Zmean+1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k))];
    confcvSize = [(Zmean+1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k)))-(Zmean-1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k)))]; 
end

T = table(M,confmc,confcv,confmcSize/confcvSize)
```

The current code returns

```
T =

  1×4 table

      M             confmc                  confcv            Var4 
    _____    ____________________    ____________________    ______

    1e+05    0.096756      0.1007    0.097306    0.097789    8.1622
```

How could I change my implementation so that all four values of M are computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified few things.Take a look at the following code.

```
randn('state',100)

%%%%%% Problem and method parameters %%%%%%%%%
S = 5; E = 6; sigma = 0.3; r = 0.05; T = 1;
Dt = 1e-2; N = T/Dt; M = [10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
confmc = zeros(numel(M), 2);
confcv = zeros(numel(M), 2);
confmcSize =  zeros(numel(M), 1);
confcvSize = zeros(numel(M), 1);
for k=1:numel(M)
    %%%%%%%%% Geom Asian exact mean  %%%%%%%%%%%%
    sigsqT= sigma^2*T*(N+1)*(2*N+1)/(6*N*N);
    muT = 0.5*sigsqT + (r - 0.5*sigma^2)*T*(N+1)/(2*N);

    d1 = (log(S/E) + (muT + 0.5*sigsqT))/(sqrt(sigsqT));
    d2 = d1 - sqrt(sigsqT);

    N1 = 0.5*(1+erf(d1/sqrt(2)));
    N2 = 0.5*(1+erf(d2/sqrt(2)));

    geo =  exp(-r*T)*( S*exp(muT)*N1 - E*N2 );
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    Spath = S*cumprod(exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*Dt+sigma*sqrt(Dt)*randn(M(k),N)),2);

    % Standard Monte Carlo
    arithave = mean(Spath,2);
    Parith = exp(-r*T)*max(arithave-E,0);  % payoffs 
    Pmean = mean(Parith);
    Pstd = std(Parith);
    confmc(k,:) = [Pmean-1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k)), Pmean+1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k))];
    confmcSize(k,1) = [(Pmean+1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k)))-(Pmean-1.96*Pstd/sqrt(M(k)))];

    % Control Variate
    geoave = exp((1/N)*sum(log(Spath),2));
    Pgeo = exp(-r*T)*max(geoave-E,0);      % geo payoffs 
    Z = Parith + geo - Pgeo;               % control variate version
    Zmean = mean(Z);
    Zstd = std(Z);
    confcv(k,:) = [Zmean-1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k)), Zmean+1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k))];
    confcvSize(k,1) = [(Zmean+1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k)))-(Zmean-1.96*Zstd/sqrt(M(k)))]; 
end

T = table(M',confmc,confcv,confmcSize./confcvSize)
```

In short, I just used a matrix instead of a vector or scalar as the members of the table. In your code, the variables (confmc, confcv, confmcSize, confcvSize) were getting overwritten.